# How can i Detect cms of a web site?

Tags: content-management-system

I have problem as I can't understand cms of websites.

who can help me to understand cms of this website

https://mrghad.ir/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site uses WordPress as their CMS.

The easiest way to check what CMS a site is using, is to use a CMS detector. Either install one as a plugin for your browser if you need it often or just do a direct search on some of the detector sites. One example would be https://whatcms.org/

You can also try to determine it yourself, by using Google chrome's devtools. From the "Elements"-tab you can try to search for clues, for example if you find references like wp-content, it is quite safe to say the site uses Wordpress. This can also be easily checked by adding wp-admin to the URL in question. If it takes you to a login screen, the site uses WordPress. This is probably the case in most sites, as it is the most popular CMS there is.